# TextView сливается с ImageView и не переносит строку

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview

Здравствуйте!
Не могу понять почему так, перепробовал разные варианты, но решения всё же нет.
Есть xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/llAction">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical">

        <TextView
                android:minLines="1"
                android:maxLines="160"
                android:singleLine = "false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="tvActionName"
                android:id="@+id/tvActionName"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"/>

        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imgIconAction"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:maxHeight="20dp"
                android:maxWidth="20dp"
                android:minHeight="10dp"
                android:minWidth="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Результат вывод этой xml выглядит так:

[image]

Как сказать текстовому полю, что бы оно остановилось перед изображением и перешло на новую строку?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте android:layout_toLeftOf

Comment: Да и еще уберите `fill_parent` - замените на `match_parent`. `fill_parent` объявлен устаревшим начиная с API 8+